# Remove seed initialization messages from R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Currently trying to output a plot in R markdown and have removed console messages that were not needed using

```
{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.width = 5, fig.height = 5}
```

However I'm still getting a seed initialization message:

```
## Seed default initialization
```

unsure how to remove this without removing the plot as would occur with `include = FALSE`.

Comment: Does this work `warning = FALSE`

Comment: No, as Seed default initialization is a message byproduct of using a random number generator so is not a warning, I think.

Comment: Oh, so quick workaround would be to create separate chunks for seed and plotting, but this is just temporal solution.

Comment: What are you using to initialise the seed? Have you tried wrapping that part in `invisible`?

Comment: just using a default seed with the function from gmp `urand.bigz(nb = 2, size = i)`. Note: i is a predefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `include = F`. You may want to put the seed in its own chunk with nothing else in that case.

Comment: `Include = F` is removing the plot unfortunately; I'll split the chunks as a last resort if there are no other options. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the message comes from a `cat` command or similar. It is slightly awkward, but you can use `capture.output` to convert it so it gets suppressed by `echo = FALSE`:

```
capture.output(x <- urand.bigz(nb = 2, size = i))
```

Then use `x` where you previously used `urand.bigz`. The reason why you need to assign to it is because the `capture.output` would otherwise suck up the return value with the `cat` message.

It only happens on the first call, so you don't need to do this for subsequent calls.